# how to rotate a rectangle in another thread without create new RotateTransform in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I developed a WPF app for real time PPI displayer. I want to rotate a rectangle that named "hand" in Animator Thread().

```
public unsafe void Animator_Thread()
            {
            RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(ins_angle);
            while (true)
                {                   
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(delegate()
                    {
                      //update hand angle
                    rotateTransform.Angle = ins_angle ;
                    hand.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
                    //hand.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(ins_angle);

                     //update Bitmap
                    image1.Source = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 
                   dpiX,dpiY,pixelFormat,myPalette,Image_Buff,stride);                        }));
                }
            }
```

but when I run thread this error appear:(

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

when I use commented line

```
//hand.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(ins_angle);
```

instead of

```
rotateTransform.Angle = ins_angle ;
hand.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
```

it works. but I don't want to create new RotateTransform at every loop because of time consuming. how can I handle this  problem ?

EDIT:  I am very beginner in c# programming. 
I continuously receive data from a LAN. For process and display this data I use multiple thread such as 
   #data acquisition thread 
   #rotate PPI hand(same as clock hand) and update displayer bitmap thread .
I figured this action in to different time at [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM6W5.png). I'w like to do this stuff in less than 5msec. but in some times this line "hand.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(ins_angle);" alone elapses more time.

and Finally my question
is any way to rotate object faster than I do?
is any way to create bitmap faster than I do?
thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. But you neither need a loop nor a thread to animate the RenderTransform of a UI element.

Just use built-in animations like in the example below, which continuously animates the Angle property of a RotateTransform by 360°/s.

```
var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
hand.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
hand.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(
    RotateTransform.AngleProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation
    {
        By = 360,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
    });
```

---

EDIT: In case you simply receive some position data in a background thread, all you need to do is to update the `Angle` property of the existing RotateTransform in a Dispatcher action.

Provided that the RenderTransform already contains a RotateTransform, which was previously assigned *once* in the UI thread:

```
hand.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ((RotateTransform)hand.RenderTransform).Angle = ins_angle);
```

In case you want to *animate* the element into the new position:

```
hand.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    hand.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(
        RotateTransform.AngleProperty,
        new DoubleAnimation(ins_angle, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
});
```

Comment: Thankful for your response. but i continuously receive data from a LAN. For process and display this data I shall use multiple thread such as
#data acquisition thread 
#rotate PPI hand(same as clock hand) and update displayer bitmap thread

Comment: Who told you so? If you receive a new angle in a background thread, it would be sufficient to assign the RotateTransform's Angle *once* in a Dispatcher.Invoke call. No loop, no extra thread. See my edit.

Comment: is any way to create bitmap faster than I do? thankful.

Comment: For your suggested edit, i've rejected it because it didn't contribute anything relevant. Note that you haven't told anything about a delta value in your question. Note also that you should not specify the `From` value of the animation here, because it should animate from the current value anyway.

Comment: Instead of creating a new BitmapSource each time, you may certainly better create a WriteableBitmap once, and only update its buffer.